# String^ из файла с переносом строк

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli

Если написать `MessageBox::Show("Строка1\nСтрока2");`
То на выходе получаем сообщение с двумя строками.

Если написать функцию чтения String^ из файла в переменную и вывести эту переменную в  MessageBox то на выходе получаем 1 строку, где "\n" останется не обработанным. И для меня это проблема, потому как весь текст всей программы я читаю их xml файлов. Как обработать "\n"?

Читаю переменную из файла так:

```
String^ Localization::txt(String^ control){
 String^ value = "";
 XElement^ str str = XElement::Load(path);
 access_localization();
 if (access) {
     try {
      value = str->Element(control)->Value;
     }
     catch (Exception^ e){
          MessageBox::Show(control + "\n\n" + e->ToString());
     }
 }
 return value;
}
```

Comment: Какое отношение ваш вопрос имеет к C++?

Comment: Потому что пишу на C++/CLI

Comment: @Smirnov Покажите Ваш код чтения из файла и содержимое файла

Comment: C++/CLI это не C++.

Comment: Что вы привязались к C++? По большому счету мой вопрос особо не привязан к CLI.

Читаю из файла так:
String^ Localization::txt(String^ control){
 String^ value = "";
 XElement^ str str = XElement::Load(path);
 access_localization();
 if (access) {
  try {
  value = str->Element(control)->Value;
  }
  catch (Exception^ e){
   MessageBox::Show(control + "\n\n" + e->ToString());
  }
 }
 return value;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно выполнить преобразование

```
str = str.Replace("\\n", "\n");
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз этот момент я и не понял. Теперь всё работает отчлично